# Tab completion that honors $CDPATH

Tags: bash, tab-completion

I've installed `bash_completion` and set my $CDPATH.  I can successfully `cd` to subdirectories of those in my $CDPATH.  What I'd like to do from here is for tab completion to bring up files in those subdirectories, such that for a file `/usr/local/foo/bar`, and my $CDPATH containing `/usr/local/foo`, I'd like to (e.g.) enter `vi b<TAB>` and have `bar` come up.  Is that possible?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I'm currently looking myself.

Comment: No luck. I've pretty well given up on it.